# springSecurityService add second authentication before building roles

Tags: grails, grails-services

I am using springSecurityService.
my flow is as followed:
step #1 :springSecurityService should check user & password.
if succeeds, 
step #2: check second authentication.
if succeeds,
step #3: build roles and log in.

I tried implementing in many ways but no success, can someone please advise?
Just to clarify, basically what i need id a two-factor authentication.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

step 1:

- install spring security plugin, for other setting read [this](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/introduction.html#configGroovy)

step 2 :

- use s2-quickstart , example :

  grails s2–quickstart com.yourapp.security User Role RequestMap

step 3 :

- configure your first account(User / Role / RequestMap) to login in bootstrap..
  read [this](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/requestMappings.html)

then you can try to login with default form by spring security..

in grails 3.0 + , you can read [this](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/newInV2.html)

so in grails 3.0+, you will get default `loginController.groovy` and `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.groovy` by spring security

but if you use grails 2.0+, you can find `loginController.groovy` in root of your controller's folder...and you can find out `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.groovy` too..but i forget that location..you can search it with tools like Intellij or other..